# How to enable BSOD memory dumps with UWF

Tags: windows, bsod, pagefile, uwf

For our industrial computers we use Unified Write Filter (UWF) on the systems. But since a recent update on some computers (30+) we experience a BSOD during shutdown `BUGCODE_NDIS_DRIVER`, tried updating drivers but with no luck.

So we want to debug the BSOD using the *.dmp file(s). But those are no where to find and the event viewer indicates why:

```
volmgr crash dump initialization failed
```

This is due to the missing pagefile which is disabled by the UWF manager. So we tried enabling pagefile on the non protect D:\ partion without luck (C:\ partion is the one protected by UWF). It still gets disabled. This also create a new message during startup of windows:

> Windows created a temporary paging file on your computer because of a problem that occurred with your paging file configuration when you started your computer. The total paging file size for all disk drives may be somewhat larger than the size you specified.

This is our batchfile to setup UWF:

```
uwfmgr volume protect c:
uwfmgr overlay set-size [[RAMSIZE]]
uwfmgr overlay set-warningthreshold [[WARNINGSIZE]]
uwfmgr overlay set-criticalthreshold [[CRITICALSIZE]]
uwfmgr file add-exclusion "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender"
uwfmgr file add-exclusion "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender"
uwfmgr file add-exclusion "C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log"
uwfmgr file add-exclusion "C:\Windows\Temp\MpCmdRun.log"
uwfmgr file add-exclusion "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client"
uwfmgr file add-exclusion "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware"
uwfmgr file add-exclusion "C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs"
uwfmgr file add-exclusion "C:\Windows\memory.dmp"
uwfmgr file add-exclusion "C:\Windows\minidump.dump"
uwfmgr registry add-exclusion "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender"
uwfmgr registry add-exclusion "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware"
uwfmgr registry add-exclusion "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones"
uwfmgr registry add-exclusion "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation"
uwfmgr registry add-exclusion "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces"
```

So hopefully someone has struggled with this before and has a properly working solution for a production environment. Took us more than a day without any luck.

Comment: The folder name is just "Minidump", not "Minidump.dump". That *could* be the problem, depending on what dump type you selected. A pagefile on the system volume may be required to get a memory dump.

Comment: Can you remote kernel debug it over the network? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-a-network-debugging-connection

Comment: @DanielB Thanks for pointing out the typo, this indeeds help. I finally ended up by disabling UWF, settings pagefile for C:\ and then tested some systems until i got the BSOD. Now i have the crashdump to investigate.

Comment: @HelpingHand Ah, i never new that this existed. Will definitely block some time to learn more about this.